# Sails.js error issue while deleting any record

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am new in sails js , Here i am follow one tutorial to create crud using sails js and mongodb.

But while deleting any record getting 500 internal server error 
console error

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:1337/user/delete/55bf315ee3437a512628916b"
```

Here is my controller file delete function:

```
 delete: function(req, res) {  

    var id=req.param("id",null);

      User.findOne(id).done(function(err, user) {

    // we now have a model with instance methods attached

    // destroy the record
    user.destroy(function(err) {

      res.redirect( 'user/index/');

      // record has been removed
    });

  });
  }
```

Here is my view

```
<a href="/user/create">+Create</a>
<ol>
<% users.forEach( function( model ){ %>
  <li><%= model.name %>(<a href="/user/delete/<%= model.id %>">delete</a>||<a href="/user/update/<%= model.id %>">Update</a>||<a href="/user/view/<%=model.id %>">view</a>)</li>
<% }); %>
</ol>
```

// Here is my route file

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },
  'post/User':{
    view: 'user/create'
  }


};
```

Please guide me  i dont't know where i am doing mistake.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake could be in the res.redirect,
you should place it outside destroy() function.

delete: function(req, res) {

```
var id=req.param("id",null);

  User.findOne(id).done(function(err, user) {

// we now have a model with instance methods attached

// destroy the record
user.destroy(function(err) {

  if (err) return

});
res.redirect( 'user/index/');
```

});
  }

Answer (score 1):

I was fixed the error , its come since i am using

```
    User.findOne(id).done(function(err, user) {
      ..
    }
```

Insted of this :

```
 User.findOne(id).exec(function(err, user) {
  ..             ^^^^^^
 }
```